# How to use TMX map object property to change objects behaviour

Tags: android, andengine

i am developing game in andEngine using Tiled maps
in TMX map i have river object and i want player will be die after falling in river

but i have no idea how to implement this

I am only able to create wall objects using this code:

```
private void createUnwalkableObjects(TMXTiledMap map)
    {
        // Loop through the object groups
         for(final TMXObjectGroup group: this.mTMXTiledMap.getTMXObjectGroups()) 
         {
             if(group.getTMXObjectGroupProperties().containsTMXProperty("wall", "true"))
             {
                 // This is our "wall" layer. Create the boxes from it
                 for(final TMXObject object : group.getTMXObjects()) 
                 {
                    final Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(object.getX(), object.getY(),object.getWidth(), object.getHeight());
                    final FixtureDef boxFixtureDef = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0, 0, 1f);
                    PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(mPhysicsWorld, rect, BodyType.StaticBody, boxFixtureDef);
                    rect.setVisible(false);
                    mScene.attachChild(rect);
                 }
             }
         }
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use the same code. In your TMX editor, create a new layer and add a property "danger" to it. You can then create any objects there (e.g. rectangles over your river tiles). Then add another if:

```
...
else if(group.getTMXObjectGroupProperties().containsTMXProperty("danger", "true"))
{
    // This is layer with dangerous objects (river etc)
    for(final TMXObject object : group.getTMXObjects()) 
    {
        // create sensor physics body and register collision detection
        // on collision, make the user die
    }
}
```